# Save and Display status updates like Twitter and Facebook?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Just a quick question, how can I set up my MySQL database for status updates?

So I already have a column horizontally for each user and a column vertically for each information stored such as their "email" and "username" and such like that. Now how do I set up a thing to make people post status updates and then store each one they post but only display the latest one they post via PHP onto their page? I mean do I make a vertical column for all users that say "statuses" or what?

Comment: Just a quick message, your question is going to be closed soon..

Comment: I'm voting to move this to dba.stackexchange.com; it's rather localized for SO

Comment: Also I recommend you read a good book on database design. It will really help you get your head around using relational databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write sql query like this to get the latest status update.

```
select * from table_name where user = your_user desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new table in your database for statuses and create a filed (in this table) that refers to the ID of the author. This is the "common way" of doing it.

And then ordering the query results is just a matter of `ORDER BY status_time DESC`.